# JavaScript Function Related Issue

Tags: javascript

I used a function with global and local variable below is my code:

```
var aNumber = 100;
tweak();

function tweak()
{
    // This prints "undefined", because aNumber is also defined locally below.
    document.write(aNumber);

    if (false)
    {
        var aNumber = 123; 
    }
}
```

What is the work of tweak();
I didn't understand.
Anyone can help me please with details?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Pease give your question a title describing what it is about--which is what?

Comment: @pherris — You just edited the question to **add** a question which is answered by a comment in the code in the question already.

Comment: @torazaburo the order is OK because the code is processed before executed. Check out hoisting: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting

Comment: @Quentin I intended to move the question from the comment up to the text above the code. The comments here show that people aren't seeing what the question actually is...

Comment: @pherris — Except the comment in the code isn't a question, it is an answer (to an unasked question).

Comment: @Quentin, ah, will check out the other answer. thx.

Comment: Any of those answers are not expected